# Azure SDK, Trace.Information and WADLogsTable

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-diagnostics

I am writing a new Cloud Service in .NET using Azure SDK 2.5.
I'm aware that there have been some significant changes to diagnostics [with the 2.5 SDK rekesae](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx).

Where I am getting conflicting information is whether or not I can still use Azure Diagnostics to capture Trace.* output to `WADLogsTable` in Azure Table Storage?

I'm aware that I can use ETW as an alternative, but that's now what I'm asking for.

According to [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/#comparing) article I can still use Trace to capture my logs with Azure Diagnostics 1.3 - which I understand has shipped with SDK 2.5.

Unfortunately I cannot get it to work.

The app.config of my worker role looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
        <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                name="AzureDiagnostics">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Throughout the code in my worker role I have tracing code that looks like this:

```cs
Trace.TraceInformation("Something happened");
```

My public diagnostics.wadcfg file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
<WadCfg>
  <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096">
    <Logs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Information" />
  </DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
</WadCfg>
<StorageAccount>mystorageAccount</StorageAccount>
</PublicConfig>
```

I have used this file to configure the diagnostics service extension using the PowerShell command:

```bsh
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension
```

No WADLogsTable is ever created. 
If I enable other diagnostics services such as Perf Counter then the relevant tables (WADPerformanceCountersTable) are created and populated.

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2012
- .NET 4.5.1
- Azure Powershell (latest v from Web Platform Installer)
- Azure SDK 2.5

Can anyone put me out of my misery?
Many Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Trace.TraceError statements with the default configuration for scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error"?

Comment: I haven't, but what makes you think that this would change anything?

Comment: Have you used Trace.Trace* style logging successfully with the new SDK version? Can you confirm that it should work?

Comment: I think you might be missing       
 <WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <DataSource name="Application!*" /></WindowsEventLog>

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm having similiar issues

Comment: Few things to check
A)local development storage is not supported in sdk 2.5
B)In role deployment config file check setting: 
<ConfigurationSettings>
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storage account name>;AccountKey=<storage account key>" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
C)You can find diagnostics related errors in below log file:
<ProjectRoot>\csx\Debug\roles\<WebRoleName>\plugins\Diagnostics\Logs\DiagnosticsPlugin.log
D)Run visual studio with admin rights when running ur web role in local compute emulator

Comment: You should have posted the full powershell commands you are using.  I have got this working, I can't see what you're missing

Answer (score 2):

How are you deploying? On the same setup (VS2012, Azure 2.5 SDK), I only saw the WADLogsTable get created using the Visual Studio "Publish" wizard, which apparently configures the diagnostics extension for you. See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx

> **Diagnostics configuration must be applied separately after deployment** - Because Azure SDK version 2.5 uses the extension model, the diagnostics extension and configuration are no longer part of the deployment package and must be applied separately after the deployment. *Visual Studio will apply the extension and configuration for you when you use the Publish wizard to deploy your application* [...]

I wasn't able to get the PowerShell cmdlets to work (didn't put much effort into that, honestly) but as a workaround, when I deployed using the VS "Publish" wizard, the WADLogsTable was created and I could see my logs flowing. This didn't happen when I packaged and uploaded through the Azure Portal.

It may be this way for the foreseeable future; the situation doesn't seem to have changed in the 2.6 SDK (though they fixed a lot of the irksomeness with diagnostics in 2.5): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn186185.aspx

Comment: We deploy from there command line using the PowerShell CmdLets.

Comment: @user1454265 then how do we achieve if we want to publish using Azure management portal and not the VS?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a default worker role that is producing trace logs and I noticed one difference in the public config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
<WadCfg>
  <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096">
    <WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
      <DataSource name="Application!*" />
    </WindowsEventLog>
    <Logs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Information" />
  </DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
</WadCfg>
<StorageAccount>mystorageAccount</StorageAccount>
</PublicConfig>
```